# How to make a layout like this image using constraint layout

Tags: android

How to make this type of view in Android Studio using constraint layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering about how to place the menu to fall half on the top view and half on the bottom view, just drag it manually to the position you want to have it, and on the design tab of Android studio select the Magic Wand icon, to "infer constraints". As for the views in the background make sure you add `app:layout_constraintBottomToTopOf="yourBottomView"` to your view on top and `app:layout_constraintTopToBottomOf="yourTopView"`.

Check the codelabs tutorial on Constraint Layout [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018#0) for more info, or the documentation on the developers' website [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what I get from the above:
[image: layout]

Comment: No this rounded view has adjusted ht these three buttons and textviews are not come in center on changing multiple devices.

Comment: @Maryam I would organise the three buttons/textviews into a separate constraint layout within the bigger layout, to make sure you keep the balance, and then constraint that layout as one item, instead of trying to center each of the views

Comment: @Maryam I edited my answer to include some guideline code for the layout